# How to access eth0 ip address for all the nodes in a Ansible template?

Tags: ansible

The current solution relies on the host name for each node in the group:

```
"{{ groups['zookeeper']|join(':2181,') }}:2181"
```

This generates a string: hostname1:2181,hostname2:2181 or something similar. I would like to use the internal IP address on eth0 instead of the hostname. Is there a similar way to access all the eth0 ip addresses in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to access hostvars with a map extract:

```
kafka_zk_string: "{{ groups['zookeeper'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_eth0', 'ipv4', 'address']) |join(':2181,') }}:2181"
```